# Add hidden input to magento cart form and show it into admin/order

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

I need to add a hidden input to my cart form and show it ( if order is ok ) into order page in admin area, is it possible?
I try to follow this http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/extending-order-object-and-hooking-on-event-in-magento/

but in 1.4.2 not work.. can someone help to to translate for 1.4.2?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the checkout success page to retrieve the last order ID and add a comment onto it.